# Definition error for 32 bit Python

Tags: python

I have a bot made to run super hexagon (just for fun) at http://pastebin.com/X34Qxrxx

Unfortunately, whenever I run it with IDLE 3.5 32 bit, I get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Spencer\Desktop\Super-Hexagon-Bot\super_hexagon_bot.py", line 223, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Spencer\Desktop\Super-Hexagon-Bot\super_hexagon_bot.py", line 213, in main
    window_handle = win32ui.FindWindow(None, u"Super Hexagon").GetSafeHwnd()
NameError: name 'win32ui' is not defined
```

Can anyone help? I'm not sure how to resolve this issue

Comment: did you load up the win32ui library?

Comment: So ? What is your question ? What did you try to fix that ?

Comment: I'm way over my head, I'm not sure how to resolve this definition issue